# Appengine channels automatically disconnected on production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

On production, a soon as I open a channel with the javascript, it disconnects a seccond after.
**Everything works super fine on devserver**. The callback works on the server but not on the client. We are using flask, backbone, requirejs and sourcemap.

Client code:

```
window.channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(window.PLAY_SETTINGS.CHANNEL_TOKEN);
window.gae_websocket = window.channel.open({
  onopen: function() {
    return console.log('onopen');
  },
  onclose: function() {
    return console.log('onclose');
  },
  onerror: function() {
    return console.log('onerror');
  },
  onmessage: function() {
    return console.log('onmessage');
  }
});
```

Server code:

```
class Connection(ndb.Model):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    scope = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True, choices=range(0, 2))
    target_key = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=True)  # Event ou debate
    channel_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

    @staticmethod
    def open_channel():
        channel_id = str(uuid4())
        channel_token = channel.create_channel(client_id=channel_id, duration_minutes=480)
        return channel_token, channel_id
```

Logs from the appengine production console.
[image: screenshot from appengine prodcution console]

The client callbacks (js) dont works. These are the server callbacks that create the logs:

```
@app.route('/_ah/channel/disconnected/', methods=['POST'])
def channel_disconnection():
    client_id = request.form.get('from')
    ndb.delete_multi(Connection.query(Connection.channel_id == client_id).fetch(keys_only=True))
    logging.info("Channel closed : %s" % client_id)
    return make_response('ok', '200')


@app.route('/_ah/channel/connected/', methods=['POST'])
def channel_connection():
    client_id = request.form.get('from')
    logging.info("Channel open : %s" % client_id)
    return make_response('ok', '200')
```